# Sql server IS_Member for other user than logged one

Tags: sql-server, impersonation

Is there any way I can find out member ship of some other user in sql server like we do for logged in user using `IS_MEMBER` function.

I am implementing impersonation and for that system should behave as the different user.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure will list all groups the user is member of:

`xp_logininfo N'domain\username','all'`